# Adding folder name to .zip files inside it

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename

I have file1.zip, file2.zip, etc. in folder called folder1. have similar folders folder2, folder3, etc.

I need to add folder name to each .zip file inside these folders.

So, files inside **folder1** will be folder1_file1.zip, folder1_file2.zip, folder1_file3.zip, etc.

Similarly, **folder2** files will be folder2_file1.zip, folder2_file2.zip, folder2_file2.zip, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So, running this script inside the directory that has `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, etc etc, it will look inside each folder and rename each of the files files present to `<directory_<filename>`.

I believe this is what you were looking for, let me know if it is not what you were looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash


for x in $(ls `pwd`); do
        if [ -d $x ]; then
                cd $x
                for f in *; do mv $f ${f/$f/$(basename `pwd`)_$f}; done
                cd ..
        fi
done
```

It's important to note that this is indiscriminant as far as file names go, if there are files inside `folder#` that you DONT want to rename, you can change the line

```
for f in *; do mv $f ${f/$f/$(basename `pwd`)_$f}; done
```

to:

```
for f in *pattern_you_are_lookingfor*; do mv $f ${f/$f/$(basename `pwd`)_$f}; done
```